# How to suppress line break after item in itemized environment?

Tags: spacing, lists

```
\textit{Research Assistant} \hfill Aug '17 - Current
\begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt % Reduce space between items
\item Developing intelligent broker algorithms in Maven based Java application to optimize simulated electrical market tariff strategies for maximization of profits.
\end{itemize}
\textit{Teaching Assistant},
```

renders this:

[image]

I have a lot of items in my resume and this is eating up space. How can I suppress this extra line so that the words "Teaching Assistant" are close the the bulleted item above it?

Comment: You should add [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to your preamble and use `\begin{itemize}[nosep]`, or set it globally `\setlist[itemize]{nosep}`.

Answer (score 7):

do you mean like this:

[image]

with use of ˙enumitem package is simple:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\textit{Research Assistant} \hfill Aug '17 - Current
\begin{itemize} %% \itemsep -2pt % <-- not needed as 'nosep' option is set
\item Developing intelligent broker algorithms in Maven based Java application 
to optimize simulated electrical market tariff strategies for maximization of profits.
\end{itemize}
\textit{Teaching Assistant}, 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes like that! One problem though, I don't have the enumitem package :( When I try to compile (?) in TeX studio it says it can't find it. I didn't install the full 3 GB installation of MacTeX cuz I felt that was way too huge. How can I get the package?

Comment: i work with miktex, which have package manager for install one (or selected number) packages or enables installing missing on the fly. probably the mactex have similar features. search on the site for "how install package with mactex".

Comment: I don't have mactex, not miktex for that matter. I'll google how to install. Thank you

Comment: well, you say in the first comment that you didn't install full "MacTeX" ..., so advise about mactex. google is one of solutions.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for remove and comment of OP's code remnant.

Comment: @Zarko - Don't mention it. :-)